# jQuery - text following cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor

I know:
Practically no javascript
Basic HTML and CSS

So - my goal: Have a short line of text follow the cursor when and only when the cursor is over a div or image.  When the cursor is not over the div or image, I do not want the text to be seen anywhere.

I found something similar on a jsFiddle page, and I have made from it the following .html and .css files:

.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="css/lern.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(index.html).bind('mousemove', function(e){
        $('#tail').css({
           left:  e.pageX + 5,
           top:   e.pageY - 20
        });
    });​
});
</script>

</head>

<body>



<div id="tail">
    <p>Farewell</p>
    <p>N.C. Hunter Hayden</p>
</div>​


</body>
</html>
```

.css file:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#tail
{
position: absolute;
}
```

This is the output:

â€‹
Farewell

N.C. Hunter Hayden

If anyone wants to take the time to patiently explain to such a green man as me, it would be appreciated much.  If you have better things to do, I totally understand.  So many things to do in a day, ya know what I mean?

I think I've given all the information I have, but if you need more, just ask.

Anyway, thanks anyway for at least deigning to read this far.  You're awesome.  Keep it up!

Have a great day.
And have a pretty good one tomorrow, too, in case I don't get a another change to tell you.

-Oijl

Answer (score 2):

Just change `index.html` to `document`.

You don't want to select the document by its filename, but by its actual selector.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/rbdFF/) it is in action.

Comment: This is so wicked...I clicked your Fiddle and moved the mouse around. Then I noticed some blueish "scratches" on my monitor. I freaked out! Anyone else getting this on Chrome? Works good though! It happens only from right to left, ha!

Comment: @Tobias: Woah, I actually get those too. Strange...I'll have to look into it.

Comment: It makes no sense, but it's pretty responsive, haha. I tried inspecting for some "lost" Fiddle classes/ids in the CSS, but no luck. Tell us if you figure it out :D